Moving mean over multiple files with lat lon and anomaly calulation
i found multiple discussions, but not the solution I'm looking for.
I have multiple Time,level, Lat, lon datafiles (Modeloutput). Now i want to calculate the Anomaly e.g. from Temp.
My Idea was to do that, by moveing averages. It is easy and fast... currently i struggle with the averages.
In python the moving averages can be compute like that:
window_size = 3
i = 0
Initialize an empty list to store moving averages
moving_averages = []

Loop through the array to consider
every window of size 3
while i < len(arr) - window_size + 1:

Store elements from i to i+window_size
in list to get the current window
window = arr[i : i + window_size]

Calculate the average of current window
window_average = round(sum(window) / window_size, 2)

Store the average of current
window in moving average list
moving_averages.append(window_average)

Shift window to right by one position
i += 1

print(moving_averages) 

so... if i have a list of data:
file =[ file1, file2, .., , n]
with file.variable['T'][:,:,:,:] how i can compute the averages over time and calc afterwards the anomalie by T[time,:,:,:] - avarage_T[on 850hPa pressure field]?
EDIT: I tried something like that:
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def load_temperature_data(file_path, variable_name):
    dataset = nc.Dataset(file_path)
    temp_data = dataset.variables[variable_name][:]
    time_data = dataset.variables['Times'][:]
    times = nc.chartostring(time_data)
    return temp_data, times

def find_relevant_files(file_list, target_time, window_size_hours):
    half_window = timedelta(hours=window_size_hours // 2)
    start_time = target_time - half_window
    end_time = target_time + half_window

    relevant_files = []
    for file_path in file_list:
        _, times = load_temperature_data(file_path, variable_name='Times')
        times_dt = [datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') for time in times]
        
        if any(start_time <= time <= end_time for time in times_dt):
            relevant_files.append(file_path)
    
    return relevant_files

def calculate_rolling_mean(file_list, variable_name, window_size_hours=3):
    rolling_mean = []
    half_window = window_size_hours // 2

    for current_file in file_list:
        temp_data, times = load_temperature_data(current_file, variable_name)
        times_dt = [datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') for time in times]

        for current_time, current_temp in zip(times_dt, temp_data):
            relevant_files = find_relevant_files(file_list, current_time, window_size_hours)
            
            temp_values = []
            for relevant_file in relevant_files:
                rel_temp_data, rel_times = load_temperature_data(relevant_file, variable_name)
                rel_times_dt = [datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') for time in rel_times]
                
                for rel_time, rel_temp in zip(rel_times_dt, rel_temp_data):
                    if current_time - timedelta(hours=half_window) <= rel_time <= current_time + timedelta(hours=half_window):
                        temp_values.append(rel_temp)
            
            rolling_mean.append(np.mean(temp_values, axis=0))
    
    return np.array(rolling_mean)

def calculate_temperature_anomaly(file_list, variable_name, rolling_mean):
    temp_anomaly = []
    mean_index = 0  # Index for the rolling_mean array
    
    for current_file in file_list:
        temp_data, _ = load_temperature_data(current_file, variable_name)
        
        for temp in temp_data:
            temp_anomaly.append(temp - rolling_mean[mean_index])
            mean_index += 1
    
    return np.array(temp_anomaly)

def extract_levels(temp_anomaly, levels, pressure_levels):
    extracted_levels = {}
    for level in levels:
        idx = np.abs(pressure_levels - level).argmin()  # Find closest pressure level index
        extracted_levels[level] = temp_anomaly[:, idx, :, :]  # Assuming data is [time, level, lat, lon]
    return extracted_levels

# Beispielaufruf
window_size_hours = 3
variable_name = 'T'

# Definiere die Liste der Dateien
wrfout_files_sorted = [
    'wrfout_file1.nc',
    'wrfout_file2.nc',
    # and so on...
]

# Define pressure levels
pressure_levels = np.array([1000, 850, 500, 300])  # Example pressure levels in hPa

rolling_mean = calculate_rolling_mean(wrfout_files_sorted, variable_name, window_size_hours)
temperature_anomaly = calculate_temperature_anomaly(wrfout_files_sorted, variable_name, rolling_mean)

# Extract levels
levels = [1000, 850, 500, 300]
extracted_levels = extract_levels(temperature_anomaly, levels, pressure_levels)

# Plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(14, 10))

level_titles = {1000: 'Ground Level', 850: '850 hPa', 500: '500 hPa', 300: '300 hPa'}
for ax, (level, data) in zip(axes.flatten(), extracted_levels.items()):
    c = ax.contourf(data[0, :, :], cmap='coolwarm')  # Plot the first time step for simplicity
    ax.set_title(level_titles[level])
    fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

But it seems wrong...
